# React Native : How to make fullscreen youtube embed video in webview with expo (without react-native link)

Tags: android, react-native, youtube, embed, expo

Does anyone know how to make an embed youtube video goes to fullscreen in Android ? The video can be played in both inline mode and fullscreen mode on iOS but in Android it plays only in inline mode and the the fullscreen button is desactivated. I use Expo and i can't eject my project so I can't use react-native link. I've search some solution but all of them need react-native link. Thank you for your answers.

```
<WebView
   javaScriptEnabled={true}
   useWebKit={true}
   domStorageEnabled={true}
   allowsInlineMediaPlayback={true}
   source={{ uri: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/TcMBFSGVi1c?playsinline=1&fs=1"}}
/>
```

Here is my code

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem before, what I did is I used `expo video`, read the documentation https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/video/ for the usage.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thank you for your help but, your solution doesn't work with YouTube links :( it works with mp4 but it shows Nothing with YouTube links

Comment: What about displaying video on iOS inline, not full screen? in HTML there is an attribute for tag <video> `playsinline=1`. How to apply it to Expo-AV ?